# Cannot preview this file - [App name] may have crashed SWIFTUI XCODE11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I try to preview build this code along with the pisteData.json data file and it builds fine but Crashes with "Cannot preview this file - [App Name] May have crashed" Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI

struct PisteRow: View {
    var pista: Structure

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            padding()
            pista.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .clipShape(Circle())

            Text(pista.name)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct PisteRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PisteRow(pista: pisteData[0])
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `pisteData[0]`?

Comment: @Asperi pisteData is the json data file and [0] should be the int to reference for the data

Comment: But your `PisteRow ` expects `Structure` for `pista` not JSON, so you have to give it `Structure` value.

Comment: @Asperi Yeah, its connected to the structure, but now its giving me the `Updating took more than 5 seconds` error...

Comment: It seems that as soon as I add the structure data it starts building but not able to preview, even on other files. but if i take it out and fill everything in with sample data put in directly it does work

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .init() Function inside the Preview to initialize a test `Structure`. Something like this:

```
struct PisteRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PisteRow(pista: .init(image: Image(systemName:"xmark"), text: "test"))
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but it wants a decoder (from: [decoder], image.......